# how to get static connection object in case of pooling?

Tags: java, apache, jakarta-ee, connection-pooling, apache-commons-dbcp

Iam unable to understand how to get connection in other classes (iam using connection pooling using DBCP)

**MyServlet** //NOT A COmplete Code

```
 class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public Datasource getDatasource(){

    Class.forName(driver).newInstance();

                ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new DriverManagerConnectionFactory(connectUri, username, password);

                PoolableConnectionFactory poolableConnectionFactory = new PoolableConnectionFactory(connectionFactory, new GenericObjectPool(null), null, "SELECT null", false, true);

                connectionPool = new GenericObjectPool(poolableConnectionFactory);
                connectionPool.setMaxActive(10);
                connectionPool.setMaxIdle(4);

return new PoolingDataSource(connectionPool);

    }
```

**Now I have something like method getConnection inside MyServlet**

```
  public static Connection getConnection () {


    }
```

**A)** How do I use datasource inside getConnection() static ethod ? I dont want to make getDatasource() as static method and then use since I feel using static dangerous when we use pooling mechanism

**B)** Please show me a way to get ultimately static getConnection() and also satisfies pooling merchanism perfectly..

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that going for `Singleton` pattern for getting connections serves the purpose.

```
1) Make a private static final PoolingDataSource reference in your
Servlet class

2) Make your getDataSource() method static. Construct the
PoolingDataSource instance when the PoolingDataSource reference in
the Servlet class is null and return it to the calling method.
Otherwise, just return the already initialized instance of
PoolingDataSource

3) Get the DataSource in the calling method and create new
connections from it

4) Close the Connection objects after use, in finally block
```

Comment: Is that not possible to get connection object inside getConnection() static method?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. that's what i have mentioned in my answer. i.e. calling method is getConnection() here

Comment: I didnt get you.. My main prob is: I can able to get connection object by doing datasource.getConnection() inside static method of getCOnnection() , BUT by doing so, made me to make 'datasource' as static..

please try to understand my problem..

Comment: May i know why do you want to have datasource as non-static? You can make getDataSource method as static and get the datasource and create connections

Comment: so, if i keep datasource variable as static, will there be any effect in connection pooling?  I have been told that we shouldn't use static in case of Datasource

Comment: There is no problem at all, using it as static reference. that is actually need. You cannot create a new instance of Datasource for getting a new connection. It would be unnecessary and costly!